# Gulp-sass 5.0 how to use compiler with import() instead of require()?

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

Gulp-sass recently updated to version 5.0. They describe that it doesn't include a compiler anymore and they say you have to install in separately.

They have documentation on how to let gulp-sass require the compiler with this piece of code.

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
```

But im using `import()` instead of `require()` and i can't find out how to translate the code they provided with `require()` to `import()`.

This is also the error i get:

```
Error in plugin "gulp-sass"
Message:

gulp-sass 5 does not have a default Sass compiler; please set one yourself. 
Both the `sass` and `node-sass` packages are permitted.
For example, in your gulpfile:

  var sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
```

For now i rolled back to version 4.1.1 which included the compiler but i would like to update it to version 5.0 at some point.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
import gulpSass from "gulp-sass";
import nodeSass from "node-sass";
    
const sass = gulpSass(nodeSass);
```

Try this.
But I still don't know if this is the best.

- I know "node-sass" should be deprecated. Just an example.
  use "dart-sass" or "sass"

Comment: How fix problem if `gulpfile.js` don't want add import ? `import gulpSass from "gulp-sass";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
`

Answer (score 6):

From [sass github repository](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass)

```
import dartSass from 'sass';
import gulpSass from 'gulp-sass';
const sass = gulpSass( dartSass );
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use import statement within the body of your code. It must be used at the beginning of the file (see [https://flexiple.com/javascript-require-vs-import/#:~:text=One%20of%20the%20major%20differences,js%20extension%20as%20opposed%20to%20.](https://flexiple.com/javascript-require-vs-import/#:%7E:text=One%20of%20the%20major%20differences,js%20extension%20as%20opposed%20to%20.))

If you or anyone is looking for how to implement the gulp code. I found a direction on Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/o9okup/error_with_gulpsass_setup/  a user - "LessRain" provided an answer:

> To install node-sass navigate to your project directory in terminal
> and run this command: npm install gulp gulp-sass node-sass gulp-concat
> --save-dev
>
> Then you can swap sass = require('gulp-sass'); for const sass =
> require("gulp-sass")(require("node-sass"));

In my case that code went into a gulpfile.js file but since it is part of a statement I had no need for "const"

```
let gulp = require('gulp'),sass = require("gulp-sass")(require("node-sass")),...
```

Comment: why do we need two brackets at the end if only one is open?

Comment: @Alex78191 the last bracker closes the thrid 'require' function

Answer (score 0):

(from error description)

var sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

Comment: why do we need two brackets at the end if only one is open?

Comment: The answer was from npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass.
You can try without that brackets but I suppose that it's used for multiple tasks.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was using npm install sass not using -g.